# Video file format won't play

Tags: file-formats, imovie

Hopefully I'm not out of line asking here, but I used to have a Sony HDR camera and of course all the files were in a sony format.  Quite some time ago I used iMovie to import them and since then I've just been storing them on a file server.  Now I'm going through my archive and trying to figure out what I want to keep and what I don't.  However, I'm having issues opening some of the files.  It seems completely random quite honestly.  Clips from the same day will work while others won't?  I've downloaded VLC for mac and pc and neither recognizes the file.  VLC has always opened everything pretty much.  Any thoughts on how I can determine if this is just a unrecognized format or a corrupt file  or something else?

Here is the a public link to the file in case you want to have a look.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/25690725/clip-2008-12-25%2009%3B21%3B23.mov

Thanks!

Comment: It seems corrupted. MovieInspector, VLC, MPlayer OSX Extended and FFmpeg can not open this file. The latter program reports `moov atom not found`.

Comment: @BartArondson that was sort of my guess as well.  Would have thought there would have been a checksum error or something if that would have been the case though?  Some of these videos are of my kid when he was first born too.  My wife is going to love me.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with file-corruption, it's just that if no a/v program can open the file at all, in my experience this often was a corrupted file. Don't throw it away yet though, other more experienced members might have a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I just downloaded the clip from provided Dropbox link and found that the file is repairable. Please try to diagnose it using **[MP4repair.org](http://mp4repair.org/)** or in case you're on a Mac computer using **[Treasured](http://aeroquartet.com/movierepair/download/)**. You will be able to repair it in a few minutes.

Regards,
Javier

(As crew of Aero Quartet I may receive some form of compensation, financial or otherwise, from my recommendation or link.)